# mysql, php retrieve data from multiples table mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to retrieve the values form two tables mysql:

```
table1 = jid, name, lat, lng

table2 = id, imgs, jid
```

My problem is that the second table could have 2 or more items. I would like to retrieve the data from the two tables in one query. Is it possible to make some thing like:

```
id name    lat  lon  imgs
1  coco   -122  210   1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg
```

I tryed with Join, union and :-(

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible to query two tables. But your question is not clear and nobody can help you here without knowing exact problem. Welcome to SO though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the result you want in one step, you will have to unload the data from the database like this for example:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table1.lat, table1.lng, table2.imgs
FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.jid = table1.jid;
```

This will build a result like this

```
id name    lat  lon  imgs
1  coco   -122  210   1.jpg
1  coco   -122  210   2.jpg
1  coco   -122  210   3.jpg
2  late   -100  270   1.jpg
2  late   -100  270   2.jpg
```

You can then process through the result set row by row and build either the page content or some new data store using a change in the `id` field to indicate that you are starting the image set for a new jid.

Comment: With MySQL one can actually use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get all of the `imgs` values into one row.  However, it's unclear if `table2` has multiple records per image or if they are all stored in one record.

Comment: @cdhowie I would like to say I had completely forgotten about `GROUP_CONCAT()` but actually I had never stumbled upon it before. Thanks for the info. I am going away right now to play with that.

Comment: It's nifty, but beware that it's a MySQL-ism and I've found no other database engine that supports this construct.  (PostgreSQL for example lets you create user-defined aggregates, so you can implement it in PostgreSQL yourself.  But it's not supported out of the box.  Though it does support `array_agg()` which does mostly the same thing, only the result is an array instead of a string.)

Comment: thanks everybody, about the doubt over table2. The table2 only stores pictures and relate with the table1 by jid

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT table2.id, table1.name, table1.lat, table1.lng, table2.imgs
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.jid = table2.jid;
```

Comment: thanks to much cdhowie, and sorry for my english, I did your sugestion but I can´t acces to the list of images in the table two. The field: imgs has 2 or mor images

Comment: @allan Show us some sample data then, it's not clear at all why this query wouldn't work.